# How to mock REST API

Tags: rest, mocking, moq

I have an MVC application that needs to invoke a REST API from a third party vendor.

The REST API should return a JSON result, but it won't be ready before we start developing and testing our MVC application, so I would like to mock the REST API (that vendors will be providing).

I researched MOQ but it doesn't seem to support mocking of REST API.

Comment: You can use online api mocking tools like https://themockapis.in/

Answer (score 2):

The best approach probably depends what requires the least learning curve and setup for you and what fits in your environment.

I have done this kind of thing using node.js and express. It was a very quick start up, and easy to do. As a minimal case I just put the json I need in files and serve them in response to REST requests. Changing the routes around to match an api is pretty easy. I am lazy sometimes about json files so I write queries in SQL to produce them, or write js code to produce them if I need a lot of data.

If you are using ASP.NET MVC (not sure that's the MVC you meant), it is pretty good as defining routes to make a REST API. You might not need extra tools.

I like a real server and a real language better than a canned tool. If you are a tester familiar with Selenium and Javascript, the Node.js approach might be the best win for you. You know the language, and don't have to invest much to get a server going.

Comment: Hi @joshp could you please clarify whats the purpose of node.js in given context?

Comment: I use as a server that can respond to any rest request with json or other content. I write code or provide files to produce the 'mock' responses I need.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with Soap UI, if you have worked with Soap UI already it should be easy.
Following are the simple steps:

- Create a Rest Project in Soap UI
- Add a new Rest mock to the project
- Add a mock action
- Add a mock response to the mock action and run the mock.

I have provided step by step instructions with downloadable examples [here](https://javacodehouse.com/mock-rest-apis-soapui)

Comment: This is 2021 - you can use https://mockswitch.com - it runs local so all your data is with you. Very easy to get started.

Comment: I agree, use on of the free tools out there that can provide you such value - try https://parrotbay.io